# How to get billing cycle from GCP using python google client api?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

Is there any way to find out the billing cycle from GCP using python google client api.

Comment: something like using this api? https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/apis

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to accept an answer (tick the check-mark next to an answer) if it answers your question. In this way your question stops to show up as _unanswered_. Also up-vote good answers. – As you're starting out here, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and have a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi,

If you feel like this is feature is not available you can [report_an_feature_request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) in Google Issue Tracker. You can open a billing api issue at this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187201&template=0) or check already opened issue at [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559770)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/libraries) is the official Google documentation on how to get the billing cycle from GCP.

For Python:

> pip (preferred):
>
> `$ pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`
>
> Setuptools: Use the easy_install tool included in the setup tools

> `package: $ easy_install --upgrade google-api-python-client`

Comment: Yes I read this doc but I wasn't able to get the exact element to fetch the billing cycle using python google client API.